# What is the keyboard shortcut to go to a file in Eclipse on Mac OS X?

Tags: eclipse, macos

What is the name of the command (or a keyboard shortcut) for jumping to a file in Eclipse?  I've seen <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, but neither this nor <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> work on Mac.

Comment: Open "Keys" in the preferences and search for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse: quick search on filename](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637702/eclipse-quick-search-on-filename)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's called "Open Resource". It's under category 'Navigate' when "In Windows" for my binding.

Comment: Thanks! (I found that it was bound to CMD-T)

Comment: Would never have thought of that .. "Resource"!! On my linux machine, I can't see the shortcuts with the menu items - is there some switch to turn it on ?

Answer (score 87):

CMD+SHIFT+r should work on the Mac

Comment: It was CMD+T on my Mac - Eclipse 3.5.2

Comment: This command will not work if you need to search for generated source code.

Comment: In windows, it is Ctrl+Shift+R

Comment: Also Ctrl + Shift + R in Linux.

Comment: `CMD + SHIFT + R`  =   Open Resource ( Lists all files .txt, .yml, .java, etc.)  
  
`CMD + SHIFT + T`  =  Open Type ( Lists Java classes )

Answer (score 14):

Other nifty shortcuts are listed here:

https://rayfd.wordpress.com/2007/05/20/10-eclipse-navigation-shortcuts-every-java-programmer-should-know/

With `Ctrl-Shift-R` (jump to file) and `Ctrl-T` (pop-up type hierarchy) I can happily spend most of my time with only the Editor view showing. You might have to modify them a bit for Mac.

Comment: this link is broken

Answer (score 4):

Browsing directly from Preferences->Keys, the combination is CMD+Shift+R

Answer (score 1):

How to open file in eclipse shot cut way
Ans. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
to open file in eclipse

Comment: The question was about "go to file" not "open file". I don't use Eclipse so don't know if these are different features but judging by the answers already posted, they are?

Answer (score 0):

As Amir pointed out <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> should work. If you are looking to not just see the code, but see where the code is in the project, you'll want to make sure your `Project Explorer` has `Link with Editor` enabled. Which is at the top right of the `Project Explorer` tab.

[image]