# Eclipse: quick search on filename

Tags: eclipse, search, eclipse-plugin, usability

Very often while working in Eclipse I realize that I remember class name, but forgot in which package this class is. Using Search is not very convenient. Too many clicks and key presses. I wonder, is there a plugin to simplify this process? For example, would be great if there was text-edit box in the top of package explorer which could filter showing packages and .java files depending of entered text. Anyone knows something like that?

Comment: http://rayfd.me/2007/05/20/10-eclipse-navigation-shortcuts-every-java-programmer-should-know/ <-- great blog post, details this and other time-saving shortcuts for opening files etc. in eclipse

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Eclipse does provide similar functions:

Open Resource <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for all resource files (including Java files)

Open Type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for all Java classes in classpath.

They also filter the list as you type.

*Note that they search all files of all opened projects in current workspace.*

Comment: what about fuzzy search like sublime text? This makes you type it exactly and you can't specify folder names to help identify which .js file inside let's say `views/users/form.html` vs `view/companies/form.html`

Comment: AFAIK, no such fuzzy search is supported by default, but you can use abbreviation and wildcard character to find files without type exactly full name. And in your example, you should able to see the path of the files under the dialog when you just type `form.html`.

Comment: Shift + Cmd + R / Shift + Cmd + T in Mac

Comment: This does not support R projects

Comment: Is it possible to expand Project Explorer at the same time?